# Multiple Threads but not locking still gives correct result

Tags: c#, multithreading

I imagined the result would be a negative value, due to not locking and multiple threads sharing the same object. I have tested this many times with release and debug version, every time the result is correct. Why is it still correct? 
Code :

```
   static BankAccount ThisbankAccount = new BankAccount(10000);
    public static void WithdrawMoney()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        ThisbankAccount.WithdrawMoney(25);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread client1 = new Thread(WithdrawMoney);
        Thread client2 = new Thread(WithdrawMoney);
        Thread client3 = new Thread(WithdrawMoney);

        client1.Start();
        client2.Start();
        client3.Start();

        client3.Join();
        Console.WriteLine( ThisbankAccount.Balance);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class BankAccount
{

    object Acctlocker = new object();

    public BankAccount(int initialAmount)
    {
        m_balance = initialAmount;
    }

    public void WithdrawMoney(int amnt)
    {
    //    lock(Acctlocker)
     //   {
            if (m_balance - amnt >= 0)
            {
                m_balance -= amnt;
            }
      //  }
    }

    public int Balance
    {
        get
        {
            return m_balance;
        }
    }

    private int m_balance;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that client1 always end sooner than client3? You're only joining the client3. you should join the others aswell

Comment: I don't know C# in particular, but one of the trickier aspects of multi-threaded programming is that you can not count on any particular behavior from an unsynchronized program.  Your three threads try 1000 withdrawals each.  Depending on your platform, it could take millions of withdrawals before you see the problem.  Or, maybe on some platform you'll never see the problem.  Or,...   Rule of thumb:  You can not count on testing to reveal threading mistakes.

Comment: Your code is incorrect even for single threaded execution. You are withdrawing 25000 from an account which only has 10000.

Comment: @mjwills Brain fart!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because something works **now** doesn't mean it is **guaranteed** to work. Race conditions are hard to trigger and might take years to surface. And when they surface, they can be *very* hard to track down and diagnose.

To see your problem in action, change this code:

```
if (m_balance - amnt >= 0)
{
    m_balance -= amnt;
}
```

to:

```
if (m_balance - amnt >= 0)
{
    Thread.Sleep(10);
    m_balance -= amnt;
}
```

*That introduces a slow enough code path to highlight the problem really easily.*

The reason you aren't spotting it with your current code is that the operations you are doing (subtraction and comparisons) are *very* fast. So the window for the [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) is very small - and you are lucky enough for it not to occur. But, over unlimited time, it *definitely* will occur.